# Android Device Chooser shows my device but my app will not start on my phone! :(

Tags: android

My Device shows up on the Android Device Chooser as:

Serial Number --     Ige-vm670-A0000028F1773B

AVD NAME -- N/A

Target -- 2.2.1 (with a green check mark next to it!)

State -- Online

Everything seems fine..So, I press the "OK" button on the bottom right hand corner of the Device Chooser screen. When I do this the Device Chooser closes and the Launching bar in eclipse eventually finishes, but then the application never starts on my phone!! :(. Am I missing something? I tried using different USB cables, switching from USB 3.0, and checking if there is enough memory on my phone but nothing seems to work :(. PLease help this newbie!! I'd much appriciate it!! ALso, i'm running eclipse in windows 8.

Comment: What does your logcat show? (Switch over from Console view)

Comment: just checking, Do you have any Launche activity.? Does it runs in any other phone or emulator.?

Comment: Does it launch on an emulator?

Comment: Please post your manifest

Answer (score 1):

following steps may help you

1)Restart your Device

2)Go to application settings and enable the USB debugging.

3)also enable other application to run on your device.

4)make sure that device status is online on android device chooser.

5)make sure that your device appear in device list in android Eclipse.

If above steps wont help you then try to run your project on emualator.And if emulator fails to launch your project then you need to see the android console

Answer (score 0):

Enabling SD-Card access may result failure of connecting to the device.
Please try to switch MTP on instead of either PTP or SD-Card